# Weird debugging situation: "There is no source code available for the current location"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2003

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in a single project written in VB.NET 2003 (legacy code). There is a MainForm and a SecondaryForm that is run by the MainForm. When I run the application through the MainForm, I can debug without any problems.

However, if I just run the SecondaryForm, I get the debug error:

> There is no source code available for the current location

when stepping over:

```
_routeId = CInt(myVar)
```

At this point I am no longer able to debug through my code window, but I have to use the disassembled code.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: As I said below, both WinForms are in the same project, so why would their references differ? That's what's confusing me!?!? Is there a setting to ignore this type of issue?

Comment: Please close, its been over a month...

Comment: Jim, did it get resolved? If so could you post the solution as an answer and accept it? If not we can just leave this open and perhaps someone else will find the solution at some point in the future

Answer (score 2):

My problem was of the Step-Into kind. I could step into a procedure inside a usercontrol just fine, but when its End Sub was encountered and I was leaving that Sub, I would get the "There is no source code available for the current location." error page.

The solution that personally worked for me was: In the Project Properties page, under "Debug", **uncheck** "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue many times... and more often than not it is a reference(s) issue.  Is it your code that has "no source" or is it Microsoft code?  Do you have multiple versions of the .NET Framework installed?

Double check your references.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple versions of .NET and VS installed.  And, it is Microsoft code "CInt()".  But, the references point doesn't make sense for 2 winforms in the same project, because they should be using the same references.

Comment: Have you ever set the option in VS to utilize the Microsoft debug symbols?

Comment: I may have.  It's VS 2003, so I don't use it very much.  Can you give me more specifics and I'll check?